# Align Image and Text in Horizontal Direction in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, flexbox, jss

I'm trying to achieve like this in the picture below. Right now, my image is on the top while the text is below. I wanted to achieve like the text is just on the right side of the image.

Pls check this codesandbox link [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-margin-yhoqy?file=/src/LoginForm.js)

[image]

**CODE**

```
const drawer = (
    <div>
      <h2 className={classes.headerTitle}>Login</h2>
      <Divider />
      <div className={classes.headerIcon}>
        <AccountCircleIcon fontSize="large" />
      </div>
      <h5 className={classes.headerName}>Bake</h5>
      <p className={classes.headerRole}>User</p>
      <Divider />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: put your headerIcon and userName and role in a div and then you could use float or more than that flex to adjust items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `display: "flex"` to children doesn't really do much. What I did was I added a wrapper class around you icon, name and role, with the `display: "flex"`, `flexDirection:"row"` `justifyContent: "center"` and `alignItems:"center"` properties. What the wrapper then does is that it puts all the divs "under" it in a row, like:

```
<div className="classes.wrapper">
  <div>This one is to the left</div>
  <div>This one is to the right</div>
</div>
```

However, if I for example put another 2 divs under the one to the right, they will stack on top of each other, because the flexDirection property is set to row **for all children under the wrapper, but not for their children.**

```
<div className="classes.wrapper">
  <div>This one is to the left</div>
  <div>
       <div>This one will be to the right on top</div>
       <div>This one will be to the right under</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also removed some other stuff, but here's the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import Hidden from "@material-ui/core/Hidden";
import AccountCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";
import "./styles.css";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  wrapper: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    margin: "0.5rem"
  },
  innerWrapper: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "baseline",
    marginLeft: "0.5rem"
  },
  headerTitle: {
    fontSize: "1.3rem",
    cursor: "pointer"
  },
  headerName: {
    margin: "0",
    fontStyle: "bold",
    fontSize: "1rem"
  },
  headerRole: {
    margin: "0",
    fontSize: "0.7rem"
  },
  iconButtons: {
    marginLeft: "auto"
  }
}));

export default function LoginForm() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const drawer = (
    <>
      <h2 className={classes.headerTitle}>Login</h2>
      <Divider />
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        {" "}
        <div className={classes.headerIcon}>
          {" "}
          <AccountCircleIcon fontSize="large" />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.innerWrapper}>
          <h5 className={classes.headerName}>Bake</h5>
          <p className={classes.headerRole}>User</p>
        </div>
        <Divider />
      </div>
    </>
  );

  return (
    <nav className={classes.drawer}>
      <Hidden lgUp implementation="css">
        <Drawer
          variant="temporary"
          anchor={"left"}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper
          }}
          ModalProps={{
            keepMounted: true
          }}
        >
          {drawer}
        </Drawer>
      </Hidden>
      <Hidden implementation="css">
        <Drawer
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper
          }}
          variant="permanent"
          open
        >
          {drawer}
        </Drawer>
      </Hidden>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

For more information on how to use flexbox in CSS, check out [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) guide.

Comment: Great! I've change my codesanbox to this. Pls check. Some few bugs, I need to align the Name and the role too just like in the picture above and some spacing on its left. Pls check. Thanks

Comment: Same principle. Add an inner wrapper around role and name, alignItems to the left, and add some margin around wrapper. Updating the code above for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have done it. I have adjusted the text on the right side of the icon.
You can do further styling:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import Hidden from "@material-ui/core/Hidden";
import AccountCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";
import "./styles.css";

const headerStyles = {
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center"
};

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  headerTitle: {
    ...headerStyles,
    fontSize: "1.3rem",
    cursor: "pointer"
  },
  headerIcon: {
    ...headerStyles,
    marginTop: "1rem"
  },
  headerName: {
    ...headerStyles,
    marginTop: "0.2rem"
  },
  headerRole: {
    ...headerStyles,
    marginTop: "-0.8rem",
    marginBottom: "1rem"
  },
  iconButtons: {
    marginLeft: "auto"
  },
  userName: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row"
  }
}));

export default function LoginForm() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const drawer = (
    <div>
      <h2 className={classes.headerTitle}>Login</h2>
      <Divider />
      <div className={classes.userName}>
        <div className={classes.headerIcon}>
          <AccountCircleIcon fontSize="large" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h5 className={classes.headerName}>Bake</h5>
          <p className={classes.headerRole}>User</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Divider />
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <nav className={classes.drawer}>
      <Hidden lgUp implementation="css">
        <Drawer
          variant="temporary"
          anchor={"left"}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper
          }}
          ModalProps={{
            keepMounted: true
          }}
        >
          {drawer}
        </Drawer>
      </Hidden>
      <Hidden implementation="css">
        <Drawer
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper
          }}
          variant="permanent"
          open
        >
          {drawer}
        </Drawer>
      </Hidden>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think there is better way to do than this

Comment: I am sure there is. This is just one option. You can give your own answer if you think that is better. I think that using flex is the simplest option here. It makes positioning objects and moving them in row or column position easier.